# Discord Bot message when user joins voice call

Tags: java, discord, bots

I've tried to make a bot that sends a message when a user joins a voice call. It doesn't show any error message, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```java
package listeners;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.voice.GuildVoiceJoinEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class voiceListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildVoiceJoin(GuildVoiceJoinEvent event){
        event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("885172885797343317").sendMessage(event.getVoiceState() + "joined voice channel" + event.getChannelJoined() + ".").queue();
    }
}
```

The main method is right I guess because another listener works.

Comment: Have you tried to print something? Is the channel id correct? Where and how you create this listener? Please, improve your question to have a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed

Answer (score 2):

I manged to get it working, I have a main startup class for my bot that links all my commands to this one class for easier coding(see below)

public class BotStartup {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("YOUR BOT TOKEN");
        
        jda.setActivity(Activity.playing("STATUS"));
        jda.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        jda.addEventListeners(new messages());
        jda.addEventListeners(new events());
        jda.addEventListeners(new Clear());
        jda.addEventListeners(new onJoin());
        jda.setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL);
        jda.setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL);
        jda.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);
        jda.build();
```

onJoin is the class ive named with your code its the same code just a different class name (see below)

```
public class onJoin extends ListenerAdapter {
@Override
public void onGuildVoiceJoin(GuildVoiceJoinEvent event){
    event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("527272203721637890").sendMessage(event.getVoiceState() + "joined voice channel" + event.getChannelJoined() + ".").queue();
}
```

}

As you can see in the first image ive used ---
jda.addEventListeners(new onJoin());---
This links the command to the start up, id advised doing this aswell as it means for easier coding linking.

This is the outcome
VS:*DISCORD SERVER*:*MyDiscordName* joined voice channelVC:General Chat - Main(*CHAT ID*).

Hope This Helped! :)